# Match projection of shapefile in cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, projection, cartopy

I am trying to make a Choropleth map using matplotlib and cartopy for which I obviously need to plot a shapefile first. However, I did not manage to do so, even though a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428512/draw-a-map-of-a-specific-country-with-cartopy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122775/how-do-i-match-the-projection-of-my-cartopy-map-with-that-of-a-shapefile). I suspect either the projection or the bounds to be misspecified.

My shapefile has the projection

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32Nz",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",32500000],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

and can be downloaded [here](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/auftrag1/archiv/vektor/vg250_ebenen/2010/vg250_2010-01-01.utm32w.shape.ebenen.zip) where I am talking about `vg250_2010-01-01.utm32w.shape.ebenen/vg250_ebenen-historisch/de1001/vg250_gem.shp`

My code is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = 'path/vg250_gem.shp'
proj = ccrs.TransverseMercator(central_longitude=0.0,central_latitude=0.0,
                           false_easting=32500000.0,false_northing=0.0,
                           scale_factor=0.9996)
municipalities = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
plt.title('Deutschland')
ax.add_geometries(municipalities,proj,edgecolor='black',facecolor='gray',alpha=0.5)
ax.set_extent([32458044.649189778*0.9, 5556418.748046352*1.1, 32465287.307457082*0.9, 5564153.5456742775*1.1],proj)
plt.show()
```

where I obtained the bounds using the corresponding method from fiona. Python throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/src/analysis/test.py", line 16, in <module>
ax.set_extent([32458044.649189778, 5556418.748046352, 32465287.307457082, 5564153.5456742775],proj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 652, in set_extent
ylim=self.projection.y_limits))
ValueError: Failed to determine the required bounds in projection coordinates. Check that the values provided are within the valid range (x_limits=[-20000000.0, 20000000.0], y_limits=[-10000000.0, 10000000.0]).
[Finished in 53.9s with exit code 1]
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Also, experimenting with ccrs.UTM() gives me a plot showing a white area. I'd appreciate it if anyone can tell me how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything about cartopy etc., but reading the next-to-last line in the error message, there are some required x and y limits listed, but the limits in your call to `set_extent` (the call which caused the error) are outside those required limits.

Comment: That is what I referred to with "This doesn't make sense to me" since I extracted the bounds of the shapefile using fiona. Above, I tried experimenting with the `set_extent` method - including deleting this line altogether - but that didn't work either.

Comment: Regardless of what bounds you were given, they are outside the bounds that cartopy is willing to accept. Again, I'm not familiar with these packages, but I notice that in the construction of `proj`, you supply a `false_easting` of 32.5M. Presumably this would result in a shift in the x direction. In your call to `set_extent`, you have two values near 32.5M that would be corrected by such a shift. Looking at the docs for cartopy, the input to `set_extent` is (x0,x1,y0,y1), but it looks like you may have given (x0,y0,x1,y1), so the `false_easting` would not get you back to acceptable bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found two issues. One is an incorrect specification of limits in your call to `set_extent`, the [documentation](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html?highlight=set_extent#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_extent) specifies `[x0,x1,y0,y1]` should be the input, you seem to have given `[x0,y0,x1,y1]`.
The other issue seems to be a limitation in cartopy, as best I can tell. It looks like projections outside the limits listed in the error message will always fail, and those limits are hardcoded. You can just edit the source ([this line in their latest release](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/v0.14.2/lib/cartopy/crs.py#L809)), changing `-2e7` to `-4e7`, likewise for the upper bound. After these fixes, your plot is generated without issue:
[image: Deutschland]
The new `set_extent` line:

```
ax.set_extent([32458044.649189778*0.975, 32465287.307457082*1.025,5556418.748046352*0.9, 556415,3.5456742775*1.1],proj)
```

You may also want to set `central_longitude=9.0` in your `TransverseMercator`, that seems to be what's specified in your shapefile.

I would recommend contacting the developers about this, they might have a good reason for setting those bounds, or they might have a better workaround, or maybe they'll widen the bounds in a later release!

**Update**

Your bounds also seem to have been set based on only the first of the `municipalities`:

```
In [34]: municipalities[0].bounds
Out[34]: (32458044.649189778, 5556418.748046352, 32465287.307457082, 5564153.5456742775)
```

But the other elements have different bounds. You can get limits flushed to the actual drawing based on min/max values of the bounds of all `municipalities`.

```
bnd = np.array([i.bounds for i in municipalities])
x0,x1 = np.min(bnd[:,0]),np.max(bnd[:,2])
y0,y1 = np.min(bnd[:,1]),np.max(bnd[:,3])
ax.set_extent([x0,x1,y0,y1],proj)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, @tsj. I don't quite understand why the bounds of the shapefile that I got using fiona don't give me exactly the smallest possible square in which the country would fit. Is the projection (still) misspecified in my code from above? Is there a mistake in Fiona, or cartopy? At least an inconsistency?

Comment: Also, just a thought, +/- 2e7 should be sufficient from the cartopy side, since the circumference of the earth is about 40e6. Maybe there's some way to change your input so that it's referenced to -7.5e6 instead of 32.5e6, then you wouldn't have to go edit the source of cartopy.

Comment: So the geometry method actually returns a shapley object which is why I can call `bounds`, right? And because this returns `(x0, y0, x1, y1)` while cartopy expects `(x0,x1,y0,y1)` I need to reorganize as you're showing in the code snippet. Got it, thanks - works like a charm.