Issue with Mismatching GSHHS and Natural Earth Shapefiles
I am trying to plot data for the region of American Samoa but I am having issues with the coastlines. I generally use the higher resolution data from the Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution Geography Database but the coastline appears shifted from the data I am plotting and from other datasets such as NaturalEarth and Google maps.
Does anyone know the source of this offset? Is this an issue with how I am plotting the coastlines, a map projection issue that I haven't taken into consideration, an issue with the GSHHS dataset, or maybe an issue with its implementation into Cartopy?
Below is an example code illustrating my issue with the island of American Samoa shifted to the west in GSHHS (blue).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy

proj = cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12,12))  


ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.GSHHSFeature(scale='f'), facecolor="blue")

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature("physical", "land", "10m"),
          ec="red", fc="yellow", lw=2, alpha=0.4)

lon_min_ = -170.9
lon_max_ = -170.55
lat_min_ = -14.4
lat_max_ = -14.2

ax.set_extent([lon_min_, lon_max_, lat_min_, lat_max_],crs=proj)

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,alpha=.4,linewidth=2, color='black', linestyle='--')

plt.show()



Looking at the GitHub issues section for Natural Earth and other questions on StackOverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122775/how-do-i-match-the-projection-of-my-cartopy-map-with-that-of-a-shapefile this may well be an issue with the dataset, and not really a programming question as a result. (although being off by several kilometres like this case seems extreme; it was easy to reproduce though, and the CRSes match)

Thanks. Ironically though the coarse resolution Natural Earth shape better represents the island position.

Here’s a modified code that includes a different projection for comparison:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy

# Using a different projection for comparison
proj = cartopy.crs.Mercator()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12,12))  

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.GSHHSFeature(scale='f'), facecolor="blue")
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature("physical", "land", "10m"),
      ec="red", fc="yellow", lw=2, alpha=0.4)

lon_min_ = -170.9
lon_max_ = -170.55
lat_min_ = -14.4
lat_max_ = -14.2

ax.set_extent([lon_min_, lon_max_, lat_min_, lat_max_], crs=proj)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, alpha=.4, linewidth=2, color='black', linestyle='--')

plt.show()


Using the mercator projection in Cartopy doesn't show anything for me and the lat/lon coordinates are distorted. This code produces an empty map.
